# I2C PIC32 ack not recognized - solved

Tags: pic, i2c

**Edited solution:**
There are 1k8 ohm pullup resistors on the Curiosity board and there are 4k7 ohm pullup resistors on the trackpad which will give a total pullup resistance of ~770 ohm at max which is too weak. Solution could be to desolder resistors from the board.

**Original problem**
I'm trying to establish I2C connection between *pic32mx470 curiosity board*(Master) and a trackpad(slave). After the slave address is sent from the PIC it can be seen on an oscilloscope that the slave pulls down SDA as to ack. However the ACKSTAT bit in I2CxSTAT register never seem change as the code hangs in:

```
LED2_Set();
if(wait_ack) while (I2C1STATbits.ACKSTAT == 1);
LED2_Clear();
```

(Whole code below, LED2 is for debugging -> LED on = it is stuck).

Below is an image from the oscilloscope and there are some anomalies such as SDA being pulled below normal operation during ack and SCL being pulled down.

[image: SDA and SCL ack'ed slave address]

I am using 4.7k pullup resistors on SDA and SCL to 3.3V. 
SDA and SCL is set as open-drain output pins in pin_manager.
The same setup ***works*** on an Arduino with the wire library, no anomalies on the oscilloscope.
Is this a hardware fault or is there something I am missing with how ACKSTAT should change? I am still unsure exactly ***how*** the master is supposed to recognizes a slave ack. Any help is greatly appreciated.

***Whole code (Except for pin_manager):***

````
#define LED2_Set()               (LATESET = (1<<6))
#define LED2_Clear()             (LATECLR = (1<<6))
#define LED2_OutputEnable()      (TRISECLR = (1<<6))

uint16_t addr = 0x74;
uint8_t write_buff[2] = {0x00, 0x11};

void I2C_init(void)
{
    I2C1CON = 0;            // Turn off I2C1 module
    I2C1CONbits.DISSLW = 1; // Disable slew rate for 100kHz 

    I2C1BRG = 0x9;     // Set baud rate
    I2C1CONbits.ON = 1;     // Turn on I2C1 module
}

void I2C_wait_for_idle(void)
{
    while(I2C1CON & 0x1F);

    while(I2C1STATbits.TRSTAT);

}

void I2C_start()
{
    I2C_wait_for_idle();
    I2C1CONbits.SEN = 1;
    while(I2C1CONbits.SEN == 1);
}

void I2C_stop()
{
    I2C_wait_for_idle();
    I2C1CONbits.PEN = 1;
}

void I2C_write(unsigned char address, char wait_ack)
{
    I2C1TRN = address | 0;
    while (I2C1STATbits.TBF == 1);
    I2C_wait_for_idle();
    LED2_Set();
    if(wait_ack) while (I2C1STATbits.ACKSTAT == 1);  // ### STUCK HERE ###
    LED2_Clear();
}

void writedata(unsigned char addr, unsigned char reg_address, unsigned char value)
{
    I2C_start();
    I2C_write(addr << 1, 1);
    I2C_write(reg_address, 1);
    I2C_write(value, 1);
    I2C_stop();
}

int main(void)
{
    // initialize the device
    I2C_init();

    LED2_OutputEnable();

    // Write to slave once then wait forever.
    writedata(addr, write_buff[0], write_buff[1]);

    while(true);

    return -1;
}
```
````

Comment: _"The same setup works on an Arduino"_ - is the Arduino also running on 3.3V, or did you use a level shifter? Do you have any info on the trackpad?

Comment: @BruceAbbott No, I used the 3v3 to power the trackpad but no level shifter for SDA and SCL. That is indeed a difference from the PIC, but the datasheet states 3v3 volt operation and not 5v so it should not work(or burn up) with the arduino, but it does work without problem. The datasheet for the trackpad module: [link](https://www.mouser.se/datasheet/2/42/proxsense_i2c_trackpad_datasheet-1626845.pdf).

Comment: _" there are some anomalies such as SDA being pulled below normal operation during ack and SCL being pulled down."_ - SDA and SCL should both go down to Ground when output from the PIC, so the anomaly is when they don't. The Curiosity board has 1k8 pullups on I2C. What happens to the waveforms if you remove the external 4k7 pullups? Also what do you get if the trackpad is disconnected?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Without ext. pullups SCL goes down towards gnd by 0.4V and SDA stays "the same" (0.06V difference). With trackpad disconnected SDA is between 0-3v3 as it should, though SCL is between 0.6-3v3 with ext. pullups and 0-3v3 without. I tried all configurations with and without internal weak pullups but they made no significant change. Thank you for your replies!

Comment: So just to clarify, without external 4k7 pullups the voltage range on both SCL and SDA is 0-3.3V, but when the trackpad is connected the voltage on SCL is 0.6-3.3V? And it still doesn't work? But it _does_ still work on the Arduino?

Comment: @BruceAbbott That is correct. When the trackpad is connected SDA looks as in the image above, regardless of pullups (just a very small change as I mentioned). However voltages lie between 0-4V when the trackpad is connected to the Arduino (since I didn't have level shifters), so both SDA and SCL does go down to 0 opposed to with the PIC.